# What was the reason for Swami Vivekananda's Death?

Tags: death, vivekananda, life-span, brahmacharya

I have always heard that because he was a pure celibate, and have never allowed his body to waste the best chemical on planet (sperm).

According to Hinduism at least this reason does not make any sense, because in Mahabharata  Bhishma was roughly 300 year old and was a pure celibate.

What was the reason for Swami Vivekananda's death?

Comment: Swami was found dead in his bed. He had some blood around his eyes and nostrils. If a Yogi leaves the body through the head, it is believed that it forces the blood up into the head. He had been looking at an almanac with a disciple 2 weeks before and when the disciple got to July 4th (the day he died), the Swami had him stop. The Swami also suffered from diabetes for over 5 years, and had been in very deteriorating health due to diabetes for 6 months before his death.

Comment: So Celibacy has nothing to do with his death, and does that mean he attained moksha ?

Comment: @@Rishi You can check my answer [here](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/16622/4732)..Swami Vivekanada must have employed the same technique where the prana vayu during death is made to leave the body through the Brahmarandhra..Highly adept Yogis can do that..BTw swamiji consulted Panchanga during those days..So although he apparently was against Jyotisha  ultimately he has to take help of it..at the time when it mattered most..

Comment: @Rickross See Taittirya Upanishad I.vi.1-2 for a description of how a Yogi leaves his body to attain Brahman. Celibacy had nothing to do with his death. Swami said that he would return one more time, not that he wanted to, but Ramakrishna was returning one more time and he had to do what Ramakrishna ordained. He said he would not return after that.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda not blood but prana has to be collected in the brain before leaving the body from higher centers .

Comment: @RakeshJoshi May i know it your own believe or you have checked the Taittirya Upanishad I.vi.1-2, as swami vivekanand was found dead with some blood around his eyes and in previous comment **Taittirya Upanishad I.vi.1-2 for a description of how a Yogi leaves his body to attain Brahman**

Comment: @Rishi why to check taittareeya Up ?

Comment: @Rishi When) the Soul attains self-sovereignty, becomes lord of the mind,
it becomes lord of speech, the lord of the eyes, the lord of the ears, the lord of knowledge;
then it becomes Brahman;
its body is the boundless space, its essential nature is the reality, truth;
its playground the life-force, its consciousness a state of bliss,
it exists in serenity, in calmness, in peace,
a state of immortality.
— Taittirĩya Upanishad, I.6.2---- where is the mention of blood gathering up in the brain ?

Comment: @RakeshJoshi No I did not know that Taittirĩya Upanishad, I.6.2 is related to blood gathering up in brain or not, but as mentioned in the first comment by swami vishwananda ji, i thought his another comment is related, Anyways so this shaloka tell us to control the mind right ?

Comment: @Rishi Prana is the vital life force which sustains life. Its not a physical substance like blood. Yogis learn how to get control over this vital force.

Comment: Yes the air which we breath is of 5 type **1. Prāṇa
2. Apāna  
3. Uḍāna  
4. Samāna  
5. Vyāna**

Comment: The upwards collective force of the prana into the head forces the blood pressure to rise in the head. The numerous small capillaries near the surface inside the nose and in and around the eyes feel the pressure the most and burst.

Comment: See also Katha U. II.iii.16 for a similar verse.

Comment: I would request anyone of you to answer using the crux of discussion, thanks

Comment: Swami himself said before his death that he felt his spirit is expanding at a much higher rate than what his body can take, so it is forced out by the spirit.

Answer (score 3):

The cause of the death is disputed. There is a detailed chronology of the last day of Swami Vivekananda in the Bengali Best Seller 'Achena Ajana Vivekananda' by Sankar.

> 9:00 pm: The Swami was lying face up.He turned on his left side. For a
>   few second his right hand shook slightly. There were beads of
>   perspiration on his forehead. Then he began to cry like a baby.
>
> 9:02-9:10 pm: He exhaled a deep breath. He remained still for 2
>   minutes and then he again exhaled a deep breadth. His head shook and
>   then fell off from the pillow. His eyes became still and an unearthly
>   glow began to emit from his smiling face.
>
> 9:30 pm: Everyone came running in thinking that the Swami has enetered
>   Samadhi. Swami Bodhananda checked the pulse and then began crying. One
>   person told someone to immediately bring Dr. Mahendra Majumdar to the
>   Belur Math. Swamis Premananda and Nischayananda started to recite
>   Ramakrishna's name in the Swami's ears to bring him down from Samadhi.
>
> 10:30 pm: Dr. Majumdar, Swamis Brahmananda and Saradananda came
>   allmost at the same time to Belur Math. Baikuntha Sanyal also came.
>   Dr. Majumdar examined the body and saw the heart has stopped. He tried
>   to artificially stimulate the heart.
>
> 12:am: Dr. Majumdar informed the inmates that the Swamiji has passed
>   away. His diagnosis was that stoppage of the heart caused the death of
>   the Swami.
>
> Vivekananda lived 39 years 5 months and 24 days. He has kept his word
>   since he had told his intimates that he will not see 40.
>
> About 3 months before his death (28 March 1902) the Swami told his
>   disciple Nivedita that 'he has given everything that he could give.
>   Now he will have to go'.
>
> Two days before his death he told his intimates that the spiritual
>   power in Belur will create a powerful movement for 1500 years.
>
> Three days before his death (1st July 1902) while walking the grounds
>   of the Belur Math the Swami showed his disciples a spot on the bank
>   of the Ganga and told them to cremate his body there.
>
> The day after death: 5 July, 1902: It was seen that the eyes of the
>   Swami were redshot and blood was oozing out of his nose and face.
>   **Dr. Bipin Ghosh said that he has died of sannyas disease (thrombosis). Dr. Mahendra Majumdar has opined that the Swami has died of heart
>   stoppage. Other doctors said that the death has been caused by torn
>   vein in the brain.**

My free translation of Achena Ajana Vivekananda by Sankar.

Comment: What is sannyas disease?

Comment: I asked around.  I was told that thrombosis was in the olden days called sannyas disease.

Comment: Why did he cry like a baby? @PradipGangopadhyay

Comment: Sankar does not give any reason for that.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever that takes a form in this world, be it a tree, a human being, a bird, a mountain, etc, has to cease to exist one day.

That is law of the NATURE.

Sages, though enlightened, do follow this Natural law.  Swami Vivekananda followed this principle of the Nature.

However, each sage will remain in this world as long as their allocated work has been accomplished.  When their allocated work is coming to an end, they choose one way or the other to leave their mortal body.

Sri Ramana Maharshi suffered with Gangrene on his hand, Sri Shirdi Sai suffered with Asthma, and so on.

Disease at the end of accomplishment of their work, will be allowed by the sages, to be a cause for departing from the body.

---

The [last days of Sri Ramakrishna Paramahamsa](https://www.ramakrishnavivekananda.info/gospel/introduction/last_days.htm) are to be remembered here.

> One day when Narendra was on the ground floor, meditating, the Master
> was lying awake in his bed upstairs. In the depths of his meditation
> Narendra felt as though a lamp were burning at the back of his head.
> Suddenly he lost consciousness. It was the yearned-for, all-effacing
> experience of nirvikalpa samadhi, when the embodied soul realizes its
> unity with the Absolute. After a very long time he regained partial
> consciousness but was unable to find his body. He could see only his
> head. "Where is my body?" he cried. The elder Gopal entered the room
> and said, "Why, it is here, Naren!" But Narendra could not find it.
> Gopal, frightened, ran upstairs to the Master. Sri Ramakrishna only
> said: "Let him stay that way for a time. He has worried me long
> enough."
>
> After another long period Narendra regained full consciousness. Bathed
> in peace, he went to the Master, who said: "Now the Mother has shown
> you everything. But this revelation will remain under lock and key,
> and I shall keep the key. **When you have accomplished the Mother's
> work you will find the treasure again.**"
>
> Some days later, Narendra being alone with the Master, Sri Ramakrishna
> looked at him and went into samadhi. Narendra felt the penetration of
> a subtle force and lost all outer consciousness. Regaining presently
> the normal mood, he found the Master weeping.
>
> Sri Ramakrishna said to him: "Today I have given you my all and I am
> now only a poor fakir, possessing nothing. ***By this power you will
> do immense good in the world, and not until it is accomplished will
> you return.***" Henceforth the Master lived in the disciple.

---

So Sri Ramakrishna Paramahamsa told him that he will remain in mortal body, as long as his allocated work is not accomplished.

Swami Vivekananda found his own way to leave the body, after accomplishing his allocated work by the DIVINE.

---

As I had stated above, disease is only an excuse to leave the body.

Answer (score 0):

Building up on the description of his last few minutes, and the fact that Yogi's have the ability to leave the body at will, by controlling involuntary functions like Heart Beat, Breathing.

I know of Om Swami ji, who is a Yogi and who has touched samadhi, and he stopped his heart beat & breathing. [ Reference: Om Swami as we know Him]
In this case, I believe Swami Vivekenanda knew when to leave and withdrew his breath/heart beat and left.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism Stack Exchange. Please do put a source to where you found this information that is presented.